# scriptblock not returning any value

Tags: powershell

In the below script `$recexternal` and `$recinternal`  always return **zero** as if there are some issues with the second block.
However, the first executes successfully and gets correct `$i` and `$e` output.
What am I doing wrong?

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010

$e = 0;
$i = 0;
$recexternal = 0;
$recinternal = 0;
$array = @("JayanManniath.Nair@contoso.com")
foreach ($user in $array) {
    $sender = Get-TransportServer |
              Get-MessageTrackingLog -ResultSize Unlimited -Sender $user 
    $sender | %{
        if (($_.Source -eq "SMTP") -and ($_.EventId -eq "SEND")) {$e++}
        if (($_.Source -eq "STOREDRIVER") -and ($_.EventId -eq "DELIVER")) {$i++}
    }

    $recipient = Get-TransportServer |
                 Get-MessageTrackingLog -ResultSize Unlimited -Recipients $user
    $reipient | %{
        if (($_.Source -eq "SMTP") -and ($_.EventId -eq "RECEIVE")) {$recexternal++}
        if (($_.Source -eq "STOREDRIVER") -and ($_.EventId -eq "DELIVER" )) {$recinternal++}
    }
}

Write-Host "$user has sent $i emails internally"
Write-Host "$user has sent $e emails externally"
Write-Host "$user has received $recexternal emails from outside organization"
Write-Host "$user has received $recinternal emails from inside the organization"
```

Comment: There seems to be a typo in variable names, `$reipient` and `$recipient`. Please double-check if that's just a copy-paste error or the culprit.

Comment: I was able to fix it thanks .it was the typo error as you said

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the obvious typo your code has the output placed wrongly,
in case of more than one `$user` in `$array` the Write-Host commands
should be placed inside the `ForEach`.

A `Where-Object` and `().count` instead of
the `ForEach-Object` (`%`) and the `IF`s is possibly more efficient.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010

$array = @("JayanManniath.Nair@contoso.com")
ForEach ($user in $array) {
    $sender = Get-TransportServer |
              Get-MessageTrackingLog -ResultSize Unlimited -Sender $user 

    $e = ($sender | Where-Object {($_.Source  -eq "SMTP") -and 
                                  ($_.EventId -eq "SEND")} ).Count
    $i = ($sender | Where-Object {($_.Source  -eq "STOREDRIVER") -and 
                                  ($_.EventId -eq "DELIVER")} ).Count

    $recipient = Get-TransportServer |
                 Get-MessageTrackingLog -ResultSize Unlimited -Recipients $user

    $recexternal = ($recipient | Where-Object {($_.Source  -eq "SMTP") -and 
                                               ($_.EventId -eq "RECEIVE")} ).Count
    $recinternal = ($recipient | Where-Object {($_.Source  -eq "STOREDRIVER") -and 
                                               ($_.EventId -eq "DELIVER")} ).Count

    Write-Host "$user has sent $i emails internally"
    Write-Host "$user has sent $e emails externally"
    Write-Host "$user has received $recexternal emails from outside organization"
    Write-Host "$user has received $recinternal emails from inside the organization"
}
```